# Capture a specific line if it exists with regex

Tags: regex

If I have files that could either be:

```
numbers:
32
45
999

56
```

or

```
numbers:
23
45

56
```

The `999` is a constant, but the other numbers & number of lines change.

Is there a way of capturing:

- above `999` followed by an empty line in the first case (i.e. excluding `999`)
- above the empty line in the second case, where `999` doesn't exist

So far I've tried:

- `(numbers:(?:\n.+)*)(\n999)` — this works great in the first case; the first group captures everything above 999. It obv doesn't work where there's no `999`, so...
- `(numbers:(?:\n.+)*)(\n999)?` — I would have thought this would work for both cases. But in the first case, this captures the `999` in the first group, I guess because it's greedy and the `?` makes the `(\n999)` optional, so the first group is free to capture it.

It's also possible I'm massively overcomplicating this and there's some easy solution.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a regex that does it **without using lookahead**:

```sh
^(numbers:(?:\n.+)*?)(?:\n(?:999)?$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GSkmW5/1/)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start line
- `(`: Start capture group #1

  - `numbers:`: Match `numbers:` text
  - `(?:\n.+)*?`: Match a line break followed by 1+ character in a line. Repeat this 0 or more times (non-greedy)
- `)`: End capture group #1
- `(?:\n(?:999)?$)`: Must be followed by a line break and `999` or empty line

Comment: That's so clever — I had tried non-greedy but without the trailing `$`, which had missed the middle lines. Thanks!

Comment: Very good solution! I thought `^(numbers:(?:\n.+)*?)(?:\n(?:999)?)$` as the solution but yours is even smarter.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```php
(numbers:(?:\n(?!999).+)*)(\n999)?
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/RNe6UF/1/).

The question mark was the right move. The `(?!999)` negative lookahead is restricting the `(.+)*` and  it does not cross optional nines.

If you do not want cross another `numbers` add to lookahead:

```php
(numbers:(?:\n(?!999|numbers:).+)*)(\n999)?
```

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    numbers:                 'numbers:'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \n                       '\n' (newline)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        999                      '999'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .+                       any character except \n (1 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2 (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \n                       '\n' (newline)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    999                      '999'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of \2 (NOTE: because you are using a
                           quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                           repetition of the captured pattern will be
                           stored in \2)
```

You prefer no lookarounds? Here:

```js
^(numbers:[\s\S]*?)\n(?:999)?$
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/3ytnxy/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    numbers:                 'numbers:'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\s\S]*?                 any character of: whitespace (\n, \r,
                             \t, \f, and " "), non-whitespace (all
                             but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more
                             times (matching the least amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \n                       '\n' (newline)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    999                      '999'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you. I'm guessing there is no way without the lookahead... (which is fine for my case)

Comment: @Maximilian So, no lookarounds? `^(numbers:[\s\S]*?)\n(?:999)?$`